# Display content of the only when user clicks it

Tags: android, tabs

I'm developing an app with tabs. The screenshot shows the content of starting activity [image]

The app has such features: navigating with tabs and a scroll view(ViewPager class). I've finally added tabs and scrolling functionality. Separately, it's working good. But by the default, tabs are loading it's content(classes have empty layout, that why it displays a map and a CircleIndicator). I need to use tabs only when the user taps it and load my main layout instead of tab content. How to implement this??? Maybe someone was already trying to implement it. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you use splash screen  kind of thing here?

Comment: No. Maybe, the issue is not that clear. When the app loads, It shows tabs content. I need the tabs to be unselected and show it's content only when user uses the tabs. What I need to display is a ViewPager, It's indicator and 3 main swipe views, like on my screenshot. It's displaying only because tab's layouts are empty :)

Comment: it should load first tabView data, and then when swipes out it should show another tabs >>

Comment: Yeap, I understand :) can I change the way it's doing it?? Cause I need to :)